# Complete at least one review task

Tags: discussion

I'm still new here and trying to fully understand how posting and answering questions are done here. I got this message and was wondering what does it mean

This is the message I received:

> Complete at least one review task. This badge is awarded once per review type.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues, once you reach 500 rep, you will have access to two of several review queues, namely the "Late Answers" and "First Posts" queues. You get a "Custodian" bronze badge for your first review task for each queue type.